# why SELECT in (IDENTIC: [version MySQL + SESSION.sql_mode + system_time_zone]) return NULL in CentOs 7 but GOAL + WARNING on W10?

Tags: mysql, time, dst, convert-tz

I know the warning is by DST, but why different results with the QUERY:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2002-10-23T15:57:03Z', 'SYSTEM', 'America/Bogota')
```

when I run the QUERY in CentOs 7 with:

```
[VERSION()] => 5.7.33
[@@SESSION.sql_mode] => ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
[@@session.time_zone] => GMT
```

from MySQL I get

```
NULL
```

when I run the QUERY in Windows 10 with:

```
[VERSION()] => 5.7.33
[@@SESSION.sql_mode] => ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
[@@session.time_zone] => GMT
```

from MySQL I get

```
[CONVERT_TZ('2002-10-23T15:57:03Z', 'GMT', 'America/Bogota')] => 2002-10-23 10:57:03
WARNING (
    [Level] => Warning
    [Code] => 1292
    [Message] => Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2002-10-23T15:57:03Z'
)
```

if BOTH servers have SAME ambient, why the result is different?

in Windows I don't have `my.ini`
this is the file `my.ini` in CentOs 7:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=53477376
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
innodb_file_per_table=1

default_storage_engine=MyIsam
default_tmp_storage_engine=MyIsam
character_set_server=utf8mb4
collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is a bit lame when it comes to timezones.

The trailing `Z` is not recognized, but I think you only get a warning.

Do you have the timezone table loaded?  (I don't know if that is a separate step on your installation.  See https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html )

This works better, but requires knowing the adjustment factor:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2002-10-23T15:57:03', 'SYSTEM', '-05:00');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2002-10-23T15:57:03', 'SYSTEM', '-05:00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2002-10-23 17:57:03                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

**TIMESTAMP**

`TIMESTAMP` is nothing more than a number -- the number of seconds from the beginning of 1970.  However, when storing/fetching, the timezone info  based on some settings converts from the system time to/from UTC:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | PDT    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The `SYSTEM` is based on the OS setting.

**DATETIME**

`DATETIME` (and the date-only `DATE`) are essentially a picture of the clock on *your* wall.  That is, there *no* information stored in it other than what you can see here:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2021-04-19 09:35:23 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No timezone information is stored.  Nor is any TZ info honored in a string:

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR('2021-04-19 09:35:23 -07:00');
+------------------------------------+
| HOUR('2021-04-19 09:35:23 -07:00') |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  9 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                      |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect time value: '2021-04-19 09:35:23 -07:00' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Sub-second**  Milliseconds example.  (Up to 6 can be used)

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(3), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3);
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| NOW(3)                  | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2021-04-19 09:49:55.292 | 2021-04-19 09:49:55.292 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Reference**

> As of MySQL 8.0.19, you can specify a time zone offset when inserting TIMESTAMP and DATETIME values into a table. The offset is appended to the time part of a datetime literal, with no intravening spaces, and uses the same format used for setting the time_zone system variable, with the following exceptions:
>
> For hour values less than than 10, a leading zero is required.
>
> The value '-00:00' is rejected.
>
> Time zone names such as 'EET' and 'Asia/Shanghai' cannot be used;
> 'SYSTEM' also cannot be used in this context.
>
> The value inserted must not have a zero for the month part, the day
> part, or both parts. This is enforced beginning with MySQL 8.0.22,
> regardless of the server SQL mode setting.

That came from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html , which may have more information of interest.

That also shows 8.0.22 having:

```
CAST(col AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

which might help you.

Comment: Thanks master @Rick James, the answer to "WHY identic ccontext ... CentOs 7 vs W10... different results" is `YOUR ANSWER`: my W10 have uploaded "timezone_2021a_posix_sql.zip" taked from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html", my CentOs 7 NO. About your "second answer": `[CONVERT_TZ('2002-10-23T15:57:03Z', 'SYSTEM', '-05:00')] => 2002-10-23 15:57:03 + WARNING` in W10 + CentOs 7. Do you know some "option/COMMAND" to get TIMEZONE from a string.datetime?, some similar to: `GET_TIME_ZONE_FROM();` with this, then I will can: `[1]get TZ from my date [2]SELECT CONVERT_TZ` without WARNING.

Comment: @Stackoverflow - I added a bunch to my Answer.  And discovered some _very_ recent changes in 8.0.

Comment: @Stackoverflow - I added the link you provided -- Could it be that one of your systems did not have that loaded?

Comment: master @Rick James I talk about: `some "function / option / COMMAND / trick" to get TIMEZONE from a string.datetime?` something similar to: `GET_TIME_ZONE_FROM(string_date_time);`

Comment: @Stackoverflow - I don't think there is any datetime function, just string functions such as MID, SUBSTR, SUBSTRING_INDEX, etc.

Comment: is true master @Rick James. Why a software so potent as MySQL, don´t recognize the char `Z` in end of a date? (neither MySQL 8.x) note: (PHP yes recognize `Z` in a date!)

Comment: @Stackoverflow - Here's one old bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8588 .  Add your "me too" to it.  Do likewise with MariaDB; sometimes they get ahead of MySQL.

Comment: thanks, I put string "MY TOO" here in stackoverflow or in [bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8588] ? again: Many Thanks @Rick James